# Is repeated measures ANCOVA appropriate in my case? Also, questions about assumptions testing

Tags: time-series, anova, repeated-measures

I'm doing a retrospective and prospective observational study with 375 patients. I have divided them in two groups according to treatment: n = 100 for group 1 and 275 for group 2. I have 8 outcome variables that I have measured over 4 time points: baseline, 12, 24 and 36 months of follow-up. I have hence decided to do a repeated measures mixed design ANOVA with one within-subject variable (Time) and one between-subject variable (treatment group).

**Questions**

A) My supervisor asked me to add covariates to my model, but, if I correctly understood my lectures from Field 2013 and Miller & Chapman 2001, it wouldn't be logical to do so since I don't have a randomized controlled design. I would only mask the true treatment effect since the covariates are not independent of the experimental effect. My supervisor told me then that I should consider only covariates that existed before the treatment, i.e. age, drug abuse before the beginning of the study, etc. I'm not quite sure this is correct, since my two groups are significantly different for these covariates. At best, I could add to my model covariates that are not different between treatment groups. What do you think?

B) Is it necessary to check for normality of residuals for each outcome variable at each time point for each group with the sample sizes I have? Since I have a lot of missing data, my sample sizes diminish to 82 and 149 for some variables, and to 24 and 57 for others.

C) I will also be doing a multiple imputations because of missing data, so do I have to check all the repeated measures ANOVA assumptions after the multiple imputations?